# ng-animate causes animation jumps

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, css-animations, ng-animate

Before I load ng-animate the animation is smooth.

```
.blue {
    background: blue;
    transition-duration: 5s;
    &.red {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

After I load ng-animate when I add and remove .red the colour will jump to red immediately then transit to blue. I don't want any beginning state of the transition when switching the class but start from whatever it was. I have to load ng-animate to do other stuff so how can I resolve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read docs. NgAnimate has many states

Comment: @evc i don't think you understand my problem here